# recognize * as command in unix

Tags: bash, unix

while passing some rgument with the "*" char, my shell recognize it
as the "ls myfolder" command , and so print to the stdout the result of this command.

Any way to fix this problem?

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2
  3 if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
  4 echo "Some arguments are missing"
  5 fi
  6
  7 #passing "*" as argument 
  8 echo $2
  9 # the result is file1.txt file2.txt...and more..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter expansions undergo pathname expansion if you don't quote them.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
  echo "Some arguments are missing"
fi

# passing "*" as argument 
echo "$2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash expands the `*` before the script is called, i.e., the `$2` var gets populated with everything that is in that directory.

It is the same as calling:

```
./script.sh with every file listed separated by spaces as arguments
```

If you reall want a `*` as a var, call the script like this:

```
./script.sh \*
```

Comment: I call the script like this - ./test.sh "blabla" "blabla *" and still it populate it with everything in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Call the script either as

```
./script \*
```

or as

```
./script '*'
```

to strip the special meaning associated with `*` ie to prevent globbing.